# Understanding Instagram Token and Limits

Tags: instagram

I am trying to establish what a token is in the instagram API. The API limit is 5000 per hour per token. Does this mean we can only call the API 5000 times collectively for all our app users or is it 5000 times per user per hour? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on whether you're using your `client_id` or `access_token.` (Recall that the client_id is app-wide while the access_token is per user.) If you're using just the client_id the limit is 5000 requests/hour app-wide, while if you're using the access_token it's 5000 requests/user/hour.

Comment: Awesome - thanks so much - access-tokens are the way to go then.

Comment: How would that work if we have a high traffic hashtag. Lets say we have 100 available access_tokens, but each need to register independently right?

Or can we combine the token to get a stream of 5000*100 posts per hour for a high traffic hashtag?

Thanks

Comment: @lazywiz From what I have seen, the streaming API does not use `access_token`s, only `client_id`s, and, from what I understand, each individual stream response does not count as an API request, only the subscription. But I am not an Instagram engineer and TBH this is better suited to a question of its own.